# Deployment without CSS for a React/Tailwind/Vite project on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, netlify

It's been a few days since I've finished a project and I can't seem to deploy it properly using Netlify. This is what I've done so far:

## Vite

To setup the project, I followed Vite's get started documentation :

```
npm create vite my-app
```

I then chose React, JS and I didn't change anything in the *vite.config.js* file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

## Tailwindcss

I did the same with Tailwind, went to the doc and followed its guidelines:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

I didn't change much in the *tailwing.config.js* file :

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      red: {
        200: "hsl(10, 79%, 85%)",
        600: "hsl(10, 79%, 65%)",
      },
      cyan: {
        200: "hsl(186, 34%, 85%)",
        600: "hsl(186, 34%, 60%)",
      },
      brown: {
        300: "hsl(28, 10%, 53%)",
        800: "hsl(25, 47%, 15%)",
      },
      cream: "hsl(27, 66%, 92%)",
      orange: "hsl(33, 100%, 93%)",
      white: "#fff",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I added the Tailwind directives to the *index.css* file :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And started working on the project after running :

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

### Project before deployment

Before deployment, the app looked exactly how I wanted: [App before deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVLSW.png). The CSS is applied properly.

## Netlify

I then went to Netlify, chose "import an existing Github project", and set [these settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49edl.png) (deploy from master, execute npm run build from dist folder).

Here are the [logs (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6HhS.png) from Netlify deploy pipeline.
And the [logs (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrMke.png).

When the site gets deployed, my app after deployment looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zTGH.png).
None of the tailwindcss has been applied, only the CSS defined in index.css is there.

I also tried to drag and drop the content of the dist folder generated using **npm run build** command to manually deploy my app. Same output.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: In the first log it says that dist/output.css doesn't exist. Did you commit it?

Comment: Indeed, removing the dist folder from the .gitgnore file fixes my issue. Thank you !
However, I don't understand why, because the **build** command is supposed to generate the required assets, including the CSS. Plus the dist folder is **gitignored by default**. Why ?

Comment: The docs mention what you said too :
"By default, the build output will be placed at dist. You may deploy this dist folder to any of your preferred platforms."

Comment: Yeah so I guess the assumption is that you’ll put that file in a CDN for optimal load times and link from there. In your case it might not make sense.